# Approximation of continuous functions by Bernstein polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, proof-verification

Recently a professor show me the following heuristic to provide approximations of continuous functions by polynomials:

> Let $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} f(\frac{k}{n}) x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$.
>
> Now, imagine a tennis club where each player receives a monetary prize of $f(p)$ if he wins a proportion $p$ of games. Then, if that player plays $n$ games, the expected value that he receives is obviously $P_n(p)$. Therefore, it is to expect that if $f$ is continuous and $n >>1$, then $P_n(p)$ is very close to $f(p)$.

My question is the following: **why is the continuity of $f$ necessary in this argument?** Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the law of large numbers, which says that if you pick the number $\frac kn$ with probability $\binom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$, then with high probability, $\frac kn$ is close to $p$.  Now you want to argue that with high probability, $f(\frac kn)$ is close to $f(p)$.  And if $f$ isn't continuous, you can't make that last step.

For example, if $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is irrational, and $0$ otherwise, then $P_n(x) = 0$, but $f(1/\sqrt 2) = 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the passage "Now you want to argue that with high probability, $f(k/n)$ is close to $f(p)$", could you please clarify what you meant? I think that I'm just using the fact that the expected value in $n$ games tends to the expect monetary prize as $n \to \infty$... Why is continuity necessary here?

Comment: Look at the example I gave.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the result is not true, but I'm not seeing in which step the heuristic fails if $f$ is not continuous...

Comment: Heuristically, any kind of fair judge of what constitutes winnings should satisfy that if two players win almost the same proportion of games, then the two players should win almost the same amount of money.  And I think you must be applying that principle without realizing it when you make your Heuristic argument.

Comment: Hmm, I don't want to be annoying, but I'm still not convinced. In which step am I using the law of large numbers?

Comment: How do you justify the heuristic?

Comment: Oh, I think I agree with you now: let $g(n)$ be the number of wins in $n$ games in a certain day. By the law of large numbers, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g(n)}{n}=p$. Hence, by continuity, $f(p)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g(n)}{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\frac{g(n)}{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty} P_n(p)$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for your patience!

Comment: You're welcome.